# applying diffrent color for same td in array

Tags: javascript

```js
(scope.arrays || []).forEach(function (a) {
    gridTemplate = gridTemplate +
        '<tr>' + 
        '   <td class="text-right">' + a.name + '</td>' +
        '   <td class="text-right">' + a.address + '</td>' +
        '   <td class="text-right">' + a.phno + '</td>' +
        '   <td class="text-right">' + a.city + '</td>' +
        '   <td class="text-right">' + a.pincode + '</td>' +
        '    <td> | </td>';
        '</tr>';
});
```

output:

If arrays length is 2, then output will be like this. 
name1 address1  phno1  city1  pincode1 | name2 address2 phno2 city2 pincode2

if i assign index value and increment inside loop and set color for even and off index means, colors are overriding.

i want to set different color for each array value. for eg, I want to set pink color for "name1 address1  phno1  city1  pincode1 " and red color for "name2 address2 phno2 city2 pincode2
"

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a snippet?

Comment: `"ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"`

Comment: could you change the demo data to something recognizable ? its a bit hard to read with just random numbers and letters in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have second argument as index in `forEach`. Use `Modulo(%)` to differentiate odd or even row and apply style accordingly.

```js
var scope = {
  arrays: [
    {name: 'name1', address: 'address1', phno: 'phno1', city: 'city1', pincode: 'pincode1'}, 
    {name: 'name2', address: 'address2', phno: 'phno2', city: 'city2', pincode: 'pincode2'}
  ]
};

gridTemplate = "";
(scope.arrays || []).forEach(function(a, index) {
  gridTemplate = gridTemplate +
    '<tr style="color: ' + (index % 2 ? '#ff0000' : '#fcbffc') + ';">' +
    '   <td class="text-right">' + a.name + '</td>' +
    '   <td class="text-right">' + a.address + '</td>' +
    '   <td class="text-right">' + a.phno + '</td>' +
    '   <td class="text-right">' + a.city + '</td>' +
    '   <td class="text-right">' + a.pincode + '</td>' +
    '   <td> | </td>';
  '</tr>';
});

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = gridTemplate;
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: if i inspect html, color was assigned correctly,but it is not reflecting in page

Comment: You can use Hexadecimal values also like '#ff0000'. Updated my answer.